# Identifier expected error trying to deploy SSRS project with custom code

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a project with this custom code:

```
Public Function GetStdDev(ByVal Sum1 as Integer, ByVal Sum2 as Integer, 
                                          ByVal Sum3 as Integer, ByVal Sum4 as Integer,
                                          ByVal Sum5 as Integer, ByVal WAvg as double) as Double
   Dim aleph = 5/60
   Dim w1 = (Sum1 - WAvg)^2 
   Dim w2 = 2 * ((Sum2 - WAvg)^2)
   Dim w3 = 3 * ((Sum3 - WAvg)^2)
   Dim w4 = 4 * ((Sum4 - WAvg)^2)
   Dim w5 = 5 * ((Sum5 - WAvg)^2)
   Dim alpha = (w1 + w2 + w3 + w4 + w5) / 5
   Dim beta = sqrt(alpha * aleph)
   Return beta
End Function
```

The report can be previewed just fine, but when I deploy it, I get this error:

```
There is an error on line 0 of custom code: [BC30203] Identifier expected.
```

I have no idea what SSRS's problem is.  Can anyone enlighten me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a classic case of rule #1 of programming: "I'm a dumbass".  The problem is I did
not put in the underscores on the function declaration as I forgot you had to do that in VB.  Why the preview did not complain, I will never know.  The corrected code is:

```
Public Shared Function GetStdDev(ByVal Sum1 as Integer, ByVal Sum2 as Integer, _ 
                                          ByVal Sum3 as Integer, ByVal Sum4 as Integer, _
                                          ByVal Sum5 as Integer, ByVal WAvg as double)     as Double
   Dim aleph as double = 5/60
   Dim w1 as double  = (Sum1 - WAvg)^2 
   Dim w2 as double = 2 * ((Sum2 - WAvg)^2)
   Dim w3 as double = 3 * ((Sum3 - WAvg)^2)
   Dim w4 as double = 4 * ((Sum4 - WAvg)^2)
   Dim w5 as double = 5 * ((Sum5 - WAvg)^2)
   Dim alpha as double = (w1 + w2 + w3 + w4 + w5) / 5
   Dim beta as double = sqrt(alpha * aleph)
   Return beta
End Function
```

Comment: Underscores were the issue. Strange how the custom code will work  without them in preview until the report is deployed to the RS Server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark the functions like:

```
Public Shared Function GetStdDev`(ByVal Sum1 as Integer, ByVal Sum2 as Integer, 
                                          ByVal Sum3 as Integer, ByVal Sum4 as Integer,
                                          ByVal Sum5 as Integer, ByVal WAvg as double) as Double
```

Comment: Nope, still having the deploy problem.